# how to import large files into textbox up to 50gb

Tags: textbox

right so, i want to load a 1.54gb text file from a url but it doesnt load cause its to big. i can load up to 100mb into the list box but nothing higher than that. i have got other programs that can upload 50 mb files and not crash or get a error. how could i do this with out getting any error and it taking over 15 mins to load.

My Code and the msg that comes up if there is an error

```
    Me.Refresh()
    Dim mimi As New WebClient With {
        .Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    }
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = mimi.DownloadString("http://comboxy.com/publiclines.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error Finding Public Lines! Your internet connection may be to slow, file may be to large or lines database may be down. :(", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Label1.Text = "Host: 0"
```

Comment: you might need to change the back stack size of your application. The default size would not be enough to hold that much data. alternatively you can try to make a background task that will keep reading and loading the textview, so that you will still be able to interract the UI

Comment: i have changed the tack size to max amount but it cant load 499mb even